# Display sqltable data as button on form

Tags: vb.net, button, display

I have a VB.NET project for restaurant management. I have an entity in the database where I store the restaurant table data (busy or not, ect).

I can show data in the `DataGridView` with this code, but this only shows as a line:

```
Dim conexao As MySqlConnection = connection
Dim comando As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("PCD_TABLE_SHOW", conexao)
comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim dt As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(comando)
Dim tabela As DataTable = New DataTable
Try
    conexao.Open()
    dt.Fill(tabela)
    FormVenda.dgvVenda.DataSource = tabela

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    conexao.Close()
End Try
```

The extrude of my table is more or less this:

```
Create table table_(Cod_table int autincrement,Name_table varchar (20),Bus_table bit,Desc_table varchar (50))
```

I just want to show the name_table field of this table as the button on the form.
I'd like to know how do I display all the button-shaped tables in the form and change the colours (if it's busy or not), as in the image below:

[image: Click here to see example image]

Comment: Have you any code that you can update the question with?

Comment: I do not have any code

Comment: OK, in the case we can't help you at this point. SO isn't a code writing service. You're going to have to do some work yourself and come back when you have a more specific issue. I'm flagging this question as too broad.

Comment: I've added the code that shows the data the way I do not want

Comment: OK retracted flag but I think it would be a good idea to try and include the structure of `tabela`. If you want to add buttons you will need to loop through the rows of `tabela`, add a `Button` control to the form and based on values do different things (set the colour etc). What do you want to happen when you click a button as each button will need to have a handler adding so that when a user clicks the button something actually happens. There is still a lot that needs clarifying otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: I already added the table structure

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the solution:

```
Dim UserButtons As List(Of Button) = New List(Of Button)
Private Sub Gettable()

    Try

        Dim conexao As MySqlConnection = connection

        conexao.Open()

        Dim cmdText As String = "PCD_SHOW_TABLE"
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(cmdText)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        ' cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1")

        Color.LightGreen.ToArgb()
        cmd.Connection = conexao

        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()

        Do While (rdr.Read())

            Dim btn As New Button
            btn.Text = rdr.GetValue(1)
            '  btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            'Dim btnColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(Val(rdr.GetValue(1)))
            'btn.BackColor = btnColor
            ' btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
            btn.Width = 100
            btn.Height = 80
            btn.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
            System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
            UserButtons.Add(btn)
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)

            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Button1_Click
        Loop

        conexao.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try
End Sub
```